# Multiple UART connection in STM32L152RB

Tags: serial-port, stm32, usart

I want to connect 2 USART (USART1 and USART2) to my board. USART1 should do both receive and transmit and USART2 takes output from board and displays it. I configured both USART1 and USART2 by their specific pins. Can anyone tell me how to configure two USARTs so that one can do both both receive and transmit and other one can only receive.